# How to avoid strange characters with Internet downloaded file names

Tags: language-support, system-language, character-set

I use Ubuntu Studio 15.10, in my desktop PC, and Lubuntu 15.10, in my laptop.

With both OS, I get strange characters into the downloaded file names from Internet. I mean, file names with spanish (latin) characters, originally.

For example: if the original file name is:

```
Danos, ¡Oh, Dios! (versión simplificada).mid,
```

I get:

```
Danos, ┬бOh, Dios! (versi├│n simplificada).mid
```

How can I fix it?

I have all the regional language (Spanish, Chile and Spain) files installed and working, without errors.

What's wrong, here?

Comment: Where do you see these characters? In the terminal (which one)? In the GUI file manager (which one)? Also, how are you downloading the files?

Comment: It happens when I receive a file through my Yahoo e-mail account (normally, *.zip compressed file). Then, when I extract it (Thunar or PCManFM), I get those rare characters. BTW, I use Mozilla Firefox as browser.